# How to change or hide my name on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Does anybody know how to change or hide my name on Twitter?

I found some tutorials on the internet, but they seem to be outdated.

I have gone through the all the settings, but I do not see any option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you mean your display name:

1. Log in
2. Click your picture in the upper right and choose "View Profile"
3. On the right side of your profile, click "Edit Profile"
4. Under your profile picture, you'll be able to edit your display name, description, location, website, and theme color
5. Click "Save changes"

If you want to change your @username:

1. Log in
2. Click your picture in the upper right and choose "Settings"
3. Change your username
4. Click "Save Changes"